# Django Links by Month

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble figuring out how to create links on a blog I'm making. I want my index page to have links to blog posts grouped by year/month.

Here is my view that will display the all the blog posts by month/year (the url will look like 2014/10 if I want to see the blog entries from October 2014):

```
def month(request, year, month):
    month_entry_list = Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=year, pub_date__month=month) 
    return render(request, 'blog/list_post_by_month.html', {
        'month_entry_list': month_entry_list
    })
```

Here is my index view:

```
def index(request):
    # latest_entry_list = Entry.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    entries = Entry.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')
    latest_entry_list = entries[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('blog/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'latest_entry_list': latest_entry_list
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

I have an idea of how to go about this but I'm not sure it's optimal. Should I just query the database to get a list of all the year/month combinations, and use that to create links in the index template?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could keep the relevant month-years in server-side cache (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) and just update it occasionally by appending to it (i.e. just checking for more posts since the last month that had one.)